# Mailchimp automation - Leaving a group

Tags: automation, mailchimp

I am busy setting up an automation workflow when someone joins a mailchimp group within a list. There are multiple groups within the list, and there are several emails that will be sent to them over time depending on which group they're in.

My question is, what happens when someone is part of the way through an automation as a result of having joined a group but then they get moved to another group. Do they stop receiving the rest of the emails that were still a part of that original groups automation?

To be clear, the above scenario is how I am hoping it works but I can't find any documentation that explicitly addresses this one way or another. I am hoping that when someone gets added to a group they start getting the automation. But then if they get moved to another group part of the way through that automation, then the remainder of that automation will no longer be sent to them.

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribers who join a group and start an automation series for that group would not be removed from that series because they join another group and start another series.

That said, I'd recommend adding segments your your automation emails that exclude subscribers who are in other groups or who are no longer in that automations groups:

Edit Automation Emails: http://eepurl.com/b2Q715

For example, let's say a subscriber joins Group A and is queued for an automation series with 3 emails. Then on Email #2 they are removed from Group A and join Group B. You can add segmentation to Emails #2 and #3 for the Group A automation that says only subscribers in Group A can receive these emails. This way, you can make sure that subscribers who started the Group A automation but then switched to another Group don't continue to receive Group A automations.

Answer (score 2):

Please, see [Adam's response](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/mailchimp-automation-leaving-a-group/113619#113619) for a proper answer.